# In app purchase stops at paymentQueue: updatedTransactions:

Tags: in-app-purchase, skdownload

I try using in-app purchases with content hosted on apple servers.
The strange thing is that when retrieving list of transactions it says that none of them contains downloads.
Currently my in-app state is "Ready to submit". Must it be submitted first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It must be submitted. And as far as I remember if it's first in-app purchase for your app - it must be submitted when you were submitting the app.